# Can Kosher Be Cooked nearby Non-Kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, restaurant

I want to start a restaurant. I would like to cater to both non-kosher and kosher populations.

If the restaurant kitchen has a separate fridge, kosher ingredients, separate stove, separate countertop, separate utensils etc. used for the kosher food prep will this suffice? Would the chef need to wear gloves?

Comment: also possibly relevant: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10566/gentile-owned-and-operated-kosher-establishment

Comment: The answer is yes. But Jews would be so wary of kosher next to non kosher and so almost no Jews would eat there for fear of cross contamination

Comment: It would probably be too complicated to work out practically/financially, even if theoretically possible.

Answer (score 2):

This is a question you should be asking to kashrut agencies, for instance

- [OU](https://oukosher.org/)
- [OK](http://www.ok.org/)
- [Star K](http://www.star-k.org/)
- or see [this broader list of agencies](http://www.kashrut.com/agencies/)

Personally I am nearly certain this is impossible because of the risks of "cross-contamination" between the two kitchen. I also never encountered such a "mixed restaurant" anywhere. The most I have seen are Israeli McDonald's with a (kosher) meat restaurant and a (kosher) dairy restaurant sharing the same premises but separated by a wall.

Comment: There's also an Israeli restaurant under rabbabut yerushalayim mehadrin that has half dairy half meat. They are mostly seperated, but you can easily walk from one side to the other (and in fact must to get to the bathroom)